# Problem getting xml in a rails3 app

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, mongrel

I'm having a pretty weird problem : requesting data with xml format in a rails 3 app works on my local environment but on my hosted environment, I get a NoMethod Error. More precisely :

undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass

Here is the method I'm talking about :

```
def getclosest
    radius = params[:radius].gsub(",",".").to_d
    origin = [params[:lat].gsub(",",".").to_d,params[:lng].gsub(",",".").to_d]

    @groceries = Grocery.within(radius, :origin => origin)

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @groceries }
        end
    end
```

This method is called when I go to the url : http://www.mysite.com/groceriesclosest/myradius/mylat/mylng

The .html works but the .xml doesnt and I get the error described above.

However, in my local environment, when I go to http://localhost:3000/groceriesclosest/radiues/lat/lng.xml it works fine

Any idea what's going wrong on my hosted version ? Btw, I'm using Mongrel as webserver.

Thanks !

**Edit**

Some precisions : first, the data set in "prod" is the same as locally and second, it's the line `format.xml  { render :xml => @groceries }` that causes the error.

Here is part of the application trace :

app/controllers/groceries_controller.rb:92:in block (2 levels) in getclosest
app/controllers/groceries_controller.rb:90:in getclosest

And some part of the full trace :

[image]

Comment: is your data set different in prod? Which line results in error?  Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Data sets are the same. I edited the message to answer your questions. Let me know if you need more from the trace. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error in the following line:

```
respond_with Article.all.comments
```

this works in console but not in my xml response.

I solved it by changing that line to

```
respond_with Article.all.comments.all
```

which gives the same response in the console though.

So maybe you could try something like

```
render :xml => @groceries.all
```

instead.